# Relation between isomorphisms of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $R$ and $S$ are vector spaces over field $F$ and $A \subset S$ is a subspace. All isomorphisms are assumed to be natural. Let $D = \{T \in Hom_F(R,S) | A \subset \ker(T)\}$. Prove $D ≈ Hom_F(S/A,R)$ and $Hom_F(S,R)/D ≈ Hom_F(A,R)$. How would you prove by constructing isomorphisms? Would you use the universal mapping property?

Comment: Is $Hom_F(R,S)$ the set of vector space homomorphisms $R\rightarrow S$ or the other way around, $S\rightarrow R$ ?

Comment: I think its the latter. Else the kernel condition doesnt make sense.$A\subset S $ and $A\subset ker(T)$ is not possible if $T:R \to S $.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\pi: S\to S/A$ denote the quotient map.

Define $\varphi: Hom_F(S/A,R)\to D$ by sending $g\mapsto g\circ \pi$ the inverse is given by $\psi(f):S/A\to R$ where $\psi(f)(x+A)=f(x)$ (the map is well-defined since $A\subset \ker(f)$.

For the other one, consider the map $\varphi: Hom_F(S,R)\to Hom_F(A,R)$ given by 
$f\mapsto f\upharpoonright A$. It is easy to show that it is onto and that the kernel is $D$ so the result follows from the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Aah, only got the inverse of the first right!!Invoking the quotient map was a slick idea. Thanks :)

Comment: @Vishesh Glad you like it